# how to implement right join in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement right join in sqlalchemy but did not find any appropriate solution.

I have tried the following::

=> is_outer = True (gives left outer join)

=> outerjoin

Comment: `A RIGHT JOIN B` is equivalent with `B LEFT JOIN A`, so just swap the operands of your join and use `outerjoin()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54350080/2681632

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RIGHT OUTER JOIN in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400307/right-outer-join-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `right outer join` does not exist in `sqlAlchemy` so you need to swap the table and use `outer_join` which is an alternate to right outer join. I hope it may help you.

```
query(Address).outerjoin(User, Address.id == User.address_id)
```

OR

```
query(User).select_entity_from(Address).join(User, isouter=True)
```