# How can I reverse the join order to get a right join with sqlalchemy using a subquery?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, left-join, flask-sqlalchemy, right-join

I'm trying to create the following (very much simplified) SQL statement with Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM

```
SELECT TableA.attr
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TableB.a_id FROM TableB) AS TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA
ON TableA.id = TableB.a_id
```

To achieve that I used the following SQLAlchemy statements

```
sq = db.session.query(distinct(TableB.a_id).label('a_id')).subquery()
results = db.session.query(TableA.attr).join(sq, sq.c.a_id==TableA.id, isouter=True).all()
```

This works however rather than joining my subquery TableB (left) with TableA (right) it does the reverse and joins TableA with TableB.

```
SELECT TableA.attr
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TableB.a_id FROM TableB) AS TableB
ON TableB.a_id = TableA.id
```

Since I understand that SQLAlchemy doesn't have a right join, I'll have to somehow reverse the order while still getting TableA.attr as the result and I can't figure out how to do that with a subquery.

Comment: x right join y on c = y left join x on c (ignoring column order)  This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400307/right-outer-join-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question was indeed the select_from() method. I.e. the actual solution to my problem were the following statements:

```
sq = db.session.query(distinct(TableB.a_id).label('a_id')).subquery()
results = db.session.query(TableA.attr) \
                    .select_from(sq) \
                    .join(TableA, TableA.id==sq.c.a_id, isouter=True).all()
```

In general terms: The select_from() method gets the left part of the join. The join() gets the right part as its first argument.